# php oop call method from inside the method from the same class

Tags: php, oop

I've got the following issue

```
class class_name {

function b() {
   // do something
}

function c() {

   function a() {
       // call function b();
   }

}

}
```

When I call function as usual: $this->b();  I get this error: Using $this when not in object context in C:...

function b() is declared as public

any thoughts?

I'll appreciate any help

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function `a()` is declared inside method `c()`.

```
<?php

class class_name {
  function b() {
    echo 'test';
  }

  function c() {

  }

  function a() {
    $this->b();
  }
}

$c = new class_name;
$c->a(); // Outputs "test" from the "echo 'test';" call above.
```

**Example using a function inside a method (not recommended)**

The reason why your original code wasn't working is because of scope of variables. `$this` is only available within the instance of the class. The function `a()` is not longer part of it so the only way to solve the problem is to pass the instance as a variable to the class.

```
<?php

class class_name {
  function b() {
    echo 'test';
  }

  function c() {
    // This function belongs inside method "c". It accepts a single parameter which is meant to be an instance of "class_name".
    function a($that) {
      $that->b();
    }

    // Call the "a" function and pass an instance of "$this" by reference.
    a(&$this);
  }
}

$c = new class_name;
$c->c(); // Outputs "test" from the "echo 'test';" call above.
```

Comment: is there any way to call it from there?

Comment: I guess it's the best practice... Ok I'll make it the way you sugested

Comment: @user681982 - If you want, I can show you an example that solves your problems but it's definitely not the right way to go.  Let me know.

Comment: I'll beter make it in the right way, but to have in a pocket new tricks is just great. If it's not too busy, could you show me this please?

Comment: Now I see why it's not recomended, in my case it's not only unrecomended but also sily. Thanks for sharing this. High five!