# how to call a function inside function on PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop

i want to use arrow function calling in php oop
i use this in PDO and i don't know how to do it by myself

````
<?php 
class Test {
   public function funcA(){
       function funcB(){
           reuturn "hello world";
       }
   }
}
// how i can use this form in PHP OOP
$class->funcA()->funcB();

?>```
````

Comment: Why have you placed a function inside another function to begin with? It's rarely necessary and doesn't really fit with core OOP design principles.

Comment: That's not how it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php oop call method from inside the method from the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6566729/php-oop-call-method-from-inside-the-method-from-the-same-class)

Comment: on PDO class you can use this
$PDO->prepare($query)->execute();
i want to know how to do it like this

Comment: `public function a() { return $this; } public function b() { return $this; }; $foo->a()->b();`